# Routing get parameters and app logic

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I have an endpoint `/` and this endpoint gets passed at times different get parameters for oAuth and logging into an app.

I've built a function for delegating these requests below called `queryAction`. Platforms like `express` allow you to route at the `path` level but not the `res.query` level, because you can't have `res.query` without a route.

For instance if I have `/?shop=thomas` and `/?login=thomas&code=7` I'm going want the user to be doing different things, different returned functions within the `app.get("/")` callback.

Here's some code that takes in a query object and returns a string based on what action should be done.

```
function queryAction(query, secret){
  query = (query) ? query : {}
  var signature = checkSignature(query, secret)
  var timestamp = checkTimestamp(query)
  var valid = signature && timestamp
  var hasInstallParams = _.hasOnly(query, ["code","shop","timestamp","signature"])
  var hasErrorParams = _.hasOnly(query, ["error","shop","timestamp","signature"])
  var hasErrorDescParams = _.hasOnly(query, ["error","error_description","shop","timestamp","signature"])
  if(!_.size(query)) return "view" // show shop login form
  if(_.hasOnly(query, ["shop"])) return "shop" // redirect to login
  if(_.hasOnly(query, ["charge_id"])) return "charge"
  if(hasInstallParams && valid) return "installed"
  if(hasInstallParams && !valid) return "installed_invalid_timestamp_and_signature"
  if(hasInstallParams && !signature) return "installed_invalid_signature"
  if(hasInstallParams && !timestamp) return "installed_invalid_timestamp"
  if(hasErrorParams && query.error == "access_denied" && valid) return "install_canceled"
  if(hasErrorParams && query.error == "access_denied" && !signature) return "install_canceled_invalid_signature"
  if(hasErrorParams && query.error == "access_denied" && !timestamp) return "install_canceled_invalid_timestamp"
  if(hasErrorParams && query.error == "access_denied" && !valid) return "install_canceled_invalid_timestamp_and_signature"
  if(hasErrorParams && query.error == "invalid_request" && valid) return "invalid_request"
  if(hasErrorParams && query.error == "invalid_request" && !signature) return "invalid_request_invalid_signature"
  if(hasErrorParams && query.error == "invalid_request" && !timestamp) return "invalid_request_invalid_timestamp"
  if(hasErrorParams && query.error == "invalid_request" && !valid) return "invalid_request_invalid_timestamp_and_signature"
  if(hasErrorDescParams && query.error == "invalid_scope" && valid) return "invalid_scope"
  if(hasErrorDescParams && query.error == "invalid_scope" && !signature) return "invalid_scope_invalid_signature"
  if(hasErrorDescParams && query.error == "invalid_scope" && !timestamp) return "invalid_scope_invalid_timestamp"
  if(hasErrorDescParams && query.error == "invalid_scope" && !valid) return "invalid_scope_invalid_timestamp_and_signature"
  return "undefined_action"
}
```

With this code I can check if a corresponding function exists and run it for instance.

```
app.get("/", function(res, req, next){
  var action = queryAction()
  if(actions[action]) return actions[action](req, res)
  return next(action)
}
```

Some of these functions would perform some database task or otherwise asynchronous task and redirect the user or render a view. I'm having a hard time juggling what express should handle (or if I even need it) and what React should handle.

- Because I want the same version of React running server-side can there be code that only runs server side and is stripped out of the client, like removing secret oAuth keys from the client-side version of react?
- Is React capable of routing params to different views / actions, like above?
- What is the line where React stops being a view engine?
- Is react capable of rendering out server-side only code and removing parts from the client before it pushes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not answer your individual questions, but the solution you are looking for is [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router).

The way I have used it with `express` is that I "catch all" the routes via `express.get(/*)` or whatever, and pipe that query down to a `react-router` handler.  Please view [this page](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/doc/00%20Guides/Server%20Rendering.md) for more information on how that works.

This allows you to route params to different views, will let you use express to remove/etc oauth keys for React, and really just act as middleware for your React components.  I am not sure what you mean by "removing parts from the client before it pushes" but you can surely do whatever you need to at this point before you render the component.

Comment: This helps. Just still doesn't paint the full picture. Let's say `/` should render out a login page form with react and `/?user=joseph` is supposed to redirect a user. Does express handel the logic for all request to `/` and if it has `?user=joseph` express does the redirect if `/` it express renders react? Or should react do the redirect?

Comment: Well, you could have express redirect if you have query parameters.  This, most likely, thought would still be a react-router problem.  You would have a react-router `Route` for `/` and then in the component you have handling that route, you can fetch the query parameters to learn that the `user=joseph`